# How to identify row using part of a factor of a column

Tags: r, character, factors, levels

I am creating a new column T_BE which I want to take a value of 1 if an existing column, theme, contains "Business and Energy".

The row I am concerned with has "Business and Energy; Economy" as the entry for theme.

Normally I use

```
df$T_BE <- 0
df$T_BE[SOAS$theme == "Business and Energy"] <-  1
```

but this time the factor is not exact.

I have tried:

```
df$T_BE <- 0
df$T_BE["Business and Energy" %in% df$theme] <-  1
```

but it doesn't work.

I will also want to do a similar selection of "Economy" to make new column, T_E

```
df%T_E <- 0
df%T_E["Economy" %in% df$theme] <- 1
```

Comment: Try `df$T_BE[grepl("Business and Energy", df$theme)] <- 1`

Comment: That works - thank you